# Torsion-free abelian groups, tensor product and $p$-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, tensor-products, abelian-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I'm studying torsion-free abelian groups and I know (see Fuchs, "Infinite Abelian Groups", vol. $2$, pp $154$) that, if $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of $p$- adic integers and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ denotes the subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ whose elements have denominator prime to $p$, then the following hold: for any torsion-free abelian group $A$ and $p$ prime number
$$A=\bigcap_p \, (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes A)$$
and
$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes A=(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap (\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$$.

Now, I'm considering the following question: can I say more (eventually assuming that $A$ has finite rank, say $n$)?

I mean that, using the facts I have stated above, $$A=(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A) \cap\bigcap_p  (\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$$ $$\subseteq \mathbb{Q}^{rank(A)}\cap\bigcap_p  (\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$$.

Does the equality hold at least in the finite rank case or this is always a strict inclusion?

Furthermore, can I write $A=\mathbb{Q}^n\cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$ in the finite rank case?

Comment: To take the intersection of groups, you need them all to be subgroups of a common group. The facts you quote from Fuchs make sense because in the first case the groups being intersected can all be naturally regarded as subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A$, and in the second case of $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$. But in which group do you want to take the intersection $(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap\bigcap_p(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$?

Comment: I see what you mean and you are right. I'm not an expert, but this idea was suggested to me by the fact that I saw in a paper (without any further justification) that there exists an algebrically closed field  of characteristic $0$, say $\Omega$, which contains $\mathbb{R}$ and all the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Thus, I thought I could argue in same way so that the above intersection makes sense in $\Omega$.

Comment: Ah, I add some context. I'm sure the equality $A=\mathbb{Q}^n\cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$ holds because it has been explicitly stated in another paper simply arguing that it was a consequence of $(\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes A$. I have tried to understand why that holds without success, but in doing so new questions arose.

Comment: Well, if $A$ has rank $n$, then $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A\cong \mathbb{Q}^n$ as abelian groups. However, to make sense of $\mathbb{Q}^n\cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$ as the intersection of two subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$, you need to know which subgroup $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is meant to be, and $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$ has *many* subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^n$ which have very different intersections with $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A$.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there are many subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with so different intersections in $\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A$ (I would like to know where I can find something more about them, whenever possible). However, reading your comment I think that, when the above equality was used, the author assumed (I will check when I can) $A$ to be also $p$-local, i.e. $A$ is $q$-divisible for any prime $q\ne p$ (this is equivalent to say that $A$ has a natural structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module). If I remember correctly, does this fact help in getting the equality?

Comment: The fact that there are lots of subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is just linear algebra: $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so has lots of $n$-dimensional subspaces. If $A$ is $p$-local, you already know that $A = (\mathbb{Q}\otimes A)\cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$, regarding all the groups concerned as subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$. To decide whether $A=\mathbb{Q}^n \cap(\mathbb{Z}_p\otimes A)$ you need to know which copy of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ inside $\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes A$ you mean ...

Comment: ... If the copy you mean is $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A$, then the equality is true, but it's just a restatement of what you already know.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I see what you mean: your explanation is very plain